# MySQL - new to setting up foreign keys to request the correct data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

Having some trouble with foreign keys, I am new to MySQL so please forgive. I am not sure how to do what I want.
I have 4 tables:

- Users
- Tasks
- Day
- Week (includes Week number and date commencing).

What I want to do is, reference each table to pull the correct data.

```
E.G. pseudo code:
find user liam, find select day associated with liam, find the task associated with the selected day, find the week from the selected day.
```

This should then allow me to sieve through the data.

Here are the tables:

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id    | int(1) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(255)    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255)    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| day_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| day        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user-id-fk | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| am_id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| am_task     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| am_color    | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+---------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type            | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| week_id | int(2) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL       | auto_increment |
| week    | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| date    | date            | NO   |     | 2014-12-29 |                |
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

So to start off I understand that I have to reference the first two tables, this is why I have created a field called 'user-id-fk'. 
I have tried to create the foreign key inside of phpMyAdmin: http://tinypic.com/r/mkar20/8

But not sure if it is working or if I have created it properly. 
As I already said I am new to MySQL so even if I had created it properly, I'm not sure how to test? 
I can add any more data if required.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Foreign keys are only ways ensuring solid data structure within SQL.  They aren't technically necessary for querying your data across two or more tables, as long as you have keys that are in common across both tables.

The use of foreign keys may make it easier to make sure you are correctly choosing items from a controlled list.  However, as they are good ideas as they ensure integrity in your database, the easiest way to test these, is to set up these keys as `RESTRICT` and test adding a record from the table that has a foreign key restriction that does not exist on the referenced table  It should provide an error.

For instance given one of your examples:

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id    | int(1) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(255)    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255)    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| day_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| day        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user-id-fk | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If `user-id-fk` is a foreign key on that second table referencing `user_id` on the first table, and  you set it up as `restrict`, you will not be able to add any records into `user-id-fk` without entering the same `user_id` into the first table.

Assuming user_id on the first table only values 1, 2, or 3 entered.  If you try to enter a row `4` into the second table, it should err, because there is no referenced key on the first table.

### Note:

You have created different sized integers for these tables, so you could run into a problem after you have entered 10 people.  I recommend making the integer size on `user_id` to be larger than 1.